# Several left join on in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select *
from House h
join Users u
on h.ID_COORD = u.ID
join PA_USERS createdBy
on h.USR_N_ID_CREATION = createdBy.ID
join Contacts c
on h.ConID= c.ID
left join Price p
on h.PriD = p.ID
join Car c
on h.CID = c.ID
left join Person p
on c.PID = p.ID
left join Assistance a
on c.AID = a.ID
left join Travel t
on p.SER_N_ID = t.SER_N_ID
left join Travel at
on a.SER_N_ID = at.SER_N_ID
where h.LEA_N_ID = 9132
and t.lang = 'en'
and p.lang = 'en'
and at.lang = 'en'
```

However because of the at.lang = 'en', the query is not returning me any data.
I need a left join on both Assistance  and Person and need the left join for both tables on the Travel table.  Any idea of how to do this.

Comment: Put those filters on the on clause

Comment: @JaimeDrq : can you please show me how?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use Whitespace when writing queries. It makes it far far easier to read not only for yourself, but others as well.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - make it easy to help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a clause in the `WHERE` without handling nullability from a `LEFT JOIN` will cause the join to implicitly become an `INNER JOIN`. Take the simple example below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.PID = B.FID
WHERE B.[name] = 'John';
```

This turns causes the `LEFT JOIN` to implicitly become an `INNER JOIN` as the clause `B.[name] = 'John'` must be true for **all rows** (regardless of if a row in `TableB` was returned).

Normally, the solution is to therefore put the requirement in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.PID = B.FID
                       AND B.Name = 'John';
```

Thus this turns your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM House h
     JOIN Users u ON h.ID_COORD = u.ID
     JOIN PA_USERS createdBy ON h.USR_N_ID_CREATION = createdBy.ID
     JOIN Contacts c ON h.ConID = c.ID
     LEFT JOIN Price p ON h.PriD = p.ID
     JOIN Car c ON h.CID = c.ID
     LEFT JOIN Person p ON c.PID = p.ID
                       AND p.lang = 'en'
     LEFT JOIN Assistance a ON c.AID = a.ID
     LEFT JOIN Travel t ON p.SER_N_ID = t.SER_N_ID
                       AND t.lang = 'en'
     LEFT JOIN Travel at ON a.SER_N_ID = at.SER_N_ID
                        AND at.lang = 'en'
WHERE h.LEA_N_ID = 9132;
```

Note that this won't fix your query anyway, as you have reused aliases. For example `Person p` and `Price p`. I haven't fixed these errors for you, as I suspect that we don't have the full query here (as the one in your question would never have run due to the alias reuse).

Answer (score 1):

Outer join means: when there is no matching record add a pseudo record with all columns set to null.

So in case there is no matching travel record, `t.lang` will be null; it will not be 'en'.

Move your conditions to the `ON` clauses to make it work:

```
left join Travel t on p.SER_N_ID = t.SER_N_ID and t.lang = 'en'
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, an `ON` condition is **not** equivelant to a where condition, as the former will still get you rows, whereas the latter will not.

Remove this for your WHERE:

```
and at.lang = 'en'
```

and add it to the LEFT JOIN's ON:

```
left join Travel at
on a.SER_N_ID = at.SER_N_ID
and at.lang = 'en'
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to do this in linQ?

Comment: @tabby you've asked about linq in a couple of the comments, however, there's no mention of it in your question. Why are you asking about Linq in the comments of the answer you've received and not in your question? If you only mention SQL Server the answers you are going to get are for SQL Server. If your question is about Linq, then ask about linq and tag it in your question, not in the comments to the answers.

Comment: Beacause in linq I am doing it like this: join p in DataAccess.GetOperations<Price>().FindAll(item => item.lang.Equals(language))
                on h.PID equals p.ID into pLeft
                from pList in pLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()  but this seems to be an 'and'.  Anw better I ask another question

Comment: @tabby don't post another question, edit your existing one. If you post another, you're likely to have it locked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `AND at.lang           = 'en'` away from the `WHERE` clause and into the `LEFT JOIN` clause. Putting in the `WHERE` clause changes the `LEFT JOIN` to a `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  *
FROM
        House       h
JOIN
        Users       u ON h.ID_COORD                     = u.ID
JOIN
        PA_USERS    createdBy ON h.USR_N_ID_CREATION    = createdBy.ID
JOIN
        Contacts    c ON h.ConID                        = c.ID
LEFT JOIN
        Price       p ON h.PriD                         = p.ID
JOIN
        Car         c ON h.CID                          = c.ID
LEFT JOIN
        Person      p ON c.PID                          = p.ID
LEFT JOIN
        Assistance  a ON c.AID                          = a.ID
LEFT JOIN
        Travel      t ON p.SER_N_ID                     = t.SER_N_ID
LEFT JOIN
        Travel      at  ON a.SER_N_ID                   = at.SER_N_ID
                        AND at.lang         = 'en'
WHERE
    h.LEA_N_ID  = 9132
AND t.lang          = 'en'
AND p.lang          = 'en'
;
```

Comment: But if I do the same thing on linq?

Comment: @tabby you've asked about linq in a couple of the comments, however, there's no mention of it in your question. Why are you asking about Linq in the comments of the answer you've received and not in your question? If you only mention SQL Server the answers you are going to get are for SQL Server. If your question is about Linq, then ask about linq and tag it in your question, not in the comments to the answers.